# Drop shadows on transparent shapes?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-canvas

[image]

I'm looking to try and implement this widget design. The one thing I'm struggling with is creating that circular dropshadow around transparency. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One solution for circles: Use a radial gradient with an array of colors and change points. You can set it so from the center to 90% out the radial gradient is transparent, then from 90% to 100% you fade from transparent to black. Something like [transparent, transparent, black, transparent] and [0, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0]